# How to get line number at runtime

Tags: delphi, debugging

is it possible to get source line number at runtime in Delphi?
I know JCL debug, but I want to avoid to use it. Also Assert is not exactly what I want. I would like to get something like this, where GetLineNumber would get the source line number. Is it possible to do it without MAP files (anyway will MAP file be generated when I use Assert) ? Is there any example ?

```
function GetLineNumber: integer;
begin
  ???
end;

procedure ThisWouldBeGreat;
begin
  if not SomeCondition then
    LogMemo.Lines.Add('Error on line: ' + IntToStr(GetLineNumber));
end;

procedure ThatsWhatIWont;
begin
  Assert(not SomeCondition, 'Error');
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the JCL debug unit? Does that also mean you want to avoid other debugging tools, like MadExcept and EurekaLog? If you want to avoid all the tools that would make your task trivially easy, then can you tell us exactly how hard you want the task to be?

Comment: Do you want something that will get the line number all by itself, usable from arbitrary locations in your program, or do you really just want a way to customize assertion handling, where specific line numbers are already available?

Comment: @Rob, for me is enough to override the Assert method as you showed in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can indeed use `Assert` for this. Write a procedure that matches the signature dictated by the `TAssertErrorProc` type, and then do whatever you want there. To preserve the expected behavior, you should probably call the original handler after you're finished.

```
procedure MichaelAssertProc(const Message, Filename: string;
  LineNumber: Integer; ErrorAddr: Pointer);
begin
  LogMessage(...);
  SysUtils.AssertErrorHandler(Message, Filename, LineNumber, ErrorAddr);
end;
```

Assign that procedure to `System.AssertErrorProc` sometime while your program starts up.

```
AssertErrorProc := MichaelAssertProc;
```

Comment: That's a workaround I will use. It gives me the ability to localize the default error message without changing the SysConst.pas file. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you use this as a debugging tool to trace errors you will seriously degrade the quality and maintainability of your source code and you will have a rather pathetic and crippled debugging tool in comparison to madExcept or other similar tools. This answers part of the question as asked but misses the bigger picture.ather pathetic and crippled debugging tool in comparison to madExcept or other similar tools. This answers part of the question as asked but misses the bigger picture.

Comment: ..., David said on his cellphone.

Comment: @Andreas I presume you are referring to the strange pattern of stray text at the end of my comments posted via Opera Mini! It's weird I know.

Comment: David: but this way of debugging will be independent of the debugging format, and thus work for e.g. the new targets without waiting for madexcept and similar tools to adapt. I like it, at least as an alternative, +1

Comment: +1. this wont compile in D5 as is. needed a bit of tweaking, but worked just fine. very nice.

Answer (score 6):

For [our logging and exception tracing classes](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons), we made a .map parser and reader.

A .map can be parsed into a binary compressed version (.mab proprietary format), which is much smaller than the original .map. For instance, a 900 KB .map file is compressed into a 70 KB .mab file - this is a much higher compression than zip.

This .mab content can be appended to the .exe, without any difference at execution, or for the end-user.

Then you can use our logging classes, or directly the .map/.mab reader class, `TSynMapFile`.

You have the following methods at hand:

```
  /// retrieve a .map file content, to be used e.g. with TSynLog to provide
  // additional debugging information
  // - original .map content can be saved as .mab file in a more optimized format
  TSynMapFile = class   
  public
    /// get the available debugging information
    // - will first search for a .map file in the .exe directory: if found,
    // will be read to retrieve all necessary debugging information - a .mab
    // file will be also created in the same directory (if MabCreate is TRUE)
    // - if .map is not not available, will search for the .mab file in the
    // .exe directory
    // - if no .mab is available, will search for a .mab appended to the exe 
    // - if nothing is available, will log as hexadecimal pointers, without
    // debugging information
    // - if aExeName is not specified, will use the current process executable
    constructor Create(const aExeName: TFileName=''; MabCreate: boolean=true);
    /// save all debugging information in the .mab custom binary format
    // - if no file name is specified, it will be saved as ExeName.mab
    // - this file content can be appended to the executable via SaveToExe method
    // - this function returns the created file name
    function SaveToFile(const aFileName: TFileName=''): TFileName;
    /// save all debugging informat in our custom binary format
    procedure SaveToStream(aStream: TStream);
    /// append all debugging information to an executable
    // - the executable name must be specified, because it's impossible to
    // write to the executable of a running process
    procedure SaveToExe(const aExeName: TFileName);
    /// add some debugging information according to the specified memory address
    // - will create a global TSynMapFile instance for the current process, if
    // necessary
    // - if no debugging information is available (.map or .mab), will write
    // the address as hexadecimal
    class procedure Log(W: TTextWriter; Addr: PtrUInt);
    /// retrieve a symbol according to an absolute code address
    function FindSymbol(aAddr: cardinal): integer;
    /// retrieve an unit and source line, according to an absolute code address
    function FindUnit(aAddr: cardinal; out LineNumber: integer): integer;
    /// return the symbol location according to the supplied absolute address
    // - i.e. unit name, symbol name and line number (if any), as plain text
    // - returns '' if no match found
    function FindLocation(aAddr: Cardinal): RawUTF8;
    /// all symbols associated to the executable
    property Symbols: TSynMapSymbolDynArray read fSymbol;
    /// all units, including line numbers, associated to the executable
    property Units: TSynMapUnitDynArray read fUnit;
  published
    /// the associated file name
    property FileName: TFileName read fMapFile;
    /// equals true if a .map or .mab debugging information has been loaded
    property HasDebugInfo: boolean read fHasDebugInfo;
  end;
```

Thanks to this class, in just one unit, you'll have all the source code line of any location.

Open source, and working with Delphi 5 up to XE (note that the .map format changed a little bit from old to newer versions - our class try to handle it).

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer addresses the following question.

> Is it possible to get source line number at runtime in Delphi?

You can't do this without a map file or something equivalent. The process of compilation leaves the source code behind.

It's not practical to litter your source code with pre-emptive checks for errors. What's more, doing so will only give you very limited information for a very limited number of faults in your code. Generally, if you can anticipate an error, you won't get it wrong. It's the errors that you don't anticipate that make it into production code.

Really you are best off using madExcept, EurekaLog or JclDebug.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So does it mean that using Assert inserts the MAP file (or only the line number where it's used) into the binary somehow?

Comment: It would be great to override AssertErrorProc if it's possible.

Comment: @michael85: Use of assert has nothing to do with the generation of a map file. When you use Assert you can still choose not to generate a map file. Also no map file will be included in your exe unless you use something like madExcept or JclDebug. Assert just raises an exception, which is caught by madExcept or JclDebug, which then uses the call stack and the map file to figure out what line triggered the exception and show what was on that line.

Comment: @Marjan, I think michael85 refers to Assert's capability to show line number in which assertion occurred and has nothing to do with madExcept or JclDebug as it works in old versions of Delphi as far as I recall.

Comment: @Im0rtality, exactly. It will be enough for me to localize the default message constant SysConst.SAssertError without changing the SysConst.pas

Comment: @Im0rtality: aha, didn't know it could. I keep learning. Can it do that also when dcu's are compiled without debug info, or when dcu's are not present, or outside the IDE? It has to get its info somewhere or is there some compiler magic going on?

Comment: It's compiler magic, @Marjan. The compiler knows that `Assert` is special (since its behavior can even be turned off). When the compiler processes an `Assert` call, it evaluates the argument, tests the result, and on failure, calls `System._Assert` with the message, file name, and line number. The compiler obviously knows the line number it needs for that specific call. No special debug information required.

Comment: Assert with its magic is not as good as it looks like. It discloses your source code file location, because the binary must include it somehow, but for my purposes will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
var  LineNumber: Integer; 

procedure MyAssert(const M, F: string; L: Integer; E: Pointer);
begin  
  LineNumber := L;
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  I: Integer;  
S: TAssertErrorProc;
begin  
  I := 0;  
  S := AssertErrorProc;  
  AssertErrorProc := MyAssert;  
  try
    Assert(I <> 0);  
  finally    
    AssertErrorProc := S;  
  end;  
  showmessage(IntToStr(LineNumber));
end;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code to make it a good answer.

Comment: All this code does is get the line number where the Assert procedure was called, can always just use Assert(False,''); instead of checking I. This is helpuf for getting the line number, that's all. NB: Instead of using the original AssertErrorProc, created my own and used that instead but reassigned the original back. Hope this makes sense. PS: Can also get the Filename from MyAssert F parameter.

Comment: I mean add some explanations to the answer (not comments), code is not always self explanatory. See how other answers are formed.

Comment: My bad, it's my first time so next time I'll make it more descriptive and add explanations to my code. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own solution for catching line numbers by assertion.

```
{$IFDEF TRACELOG} 
try 
    assert(0=1,''); 
except on E : Exception do 
    tracelog(E.Message); 
end; 
{$ENDIF}
```

where `tracelog()` is:

```
procedure TraceLog(LogMessage: WideString);
var
    tfile : TextFile;
    logTime : WideString;
begin
    logTime := formatDateTime('YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.zzz',Now);
    logMessage := Copy(LogMessage,pos(', line ',LogMessage)+7,pos(')',LogMessage) - pos(', line ',LogMessage) - 7);

    Assign(tfile,SrcDir+'data\TraceLog.txt');
    if FileExists(SrcDir+'data\TraceLog.txt') then Append(tfile) else Rewrite(tfile);
    Writeln(tfile,'{' + logTime + '} [' + LogMessage + ']');
    CloseFile(tfile);
end;
```

and you can Enable/Disable this with Debugger flag

```
{$DEFINE TRACELOG}
```

I hope that helps you. I found it a great solution for debuging and tracing linenumbers, let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: Ouch. Very creative. :-) Look at [Rob's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7215263/1431618) for a better way use Assert for this.

Comment: Just a reminder: triggering exceptions has a huge performance cost. And, from the logical/architectural point of view, my opinion is that [Exceptions should be exceptional](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/04/12/Why-Transmitting-Exceptions-in-SOA-services-is-not-a-good-idea).The trendy GO language [does not have exceptions](https://golang.org/doc/faq#exceptions)!