# Is there a delphi equivalent of C's __FILE__ or __LINE__ preprocessor directives

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have some error handling that I'd really like to be able to indicate the source file name in the error message.

Back in the C world we have `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` preprocessor directives.
Is there a functionally equivalent way of doing the same thing in Delphi?

Comment: There is no such thing exactly, but take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214213/how-to-get-line-number-at-runtime

Comment: Take a look at madExcept and similar tools.